# How to use ExecuteScalar() to get a value and give it to your textbox.text?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, return, executescalar

this is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InvoiceTable] (
    [Id]                 INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [CodeColumn]         NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [NameColumn]         NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [QTYColumn]          INT           NULL,
    [TotalQTYColumn]     INT           NULL,
    [UnitCostColumn]     INT           NOT NULL,
    [DiscountRateColumn] FLOAT (53)    DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    [RowTotalColumn]     AS            (([QTYColumn]*[UnitCostColumn])*((1)-[DiscountRateColumn])) PERSISTED,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

I have an Invoice form and a Confirimation form. User selects the desired goods in the first form and confirms how much he/she should pay in the second form. I want my program to show the value of `sum(RowTotalColumn)` as a text in my TotalCostTextBox.Text.
I wrote the following code:

```
private int ConfirmForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectQuery = "SELECT Sum(RowTotalColumn) FROM InvoiceTable";
    var sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, sqlcon);
    var result = sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar();
    return int.Parse(result.ToString());
    TotalCostTextBox1.Text = result.ToString();
```

when I put `TotalCostTextBox1.Text = result.ToString();` after `return` it yells

> Unreachable code detected

when I put it before `return`, `TotalCostTextBox1` shows nothing...

Please tell me how to fill the TotalCostTextBox1 with the value. not about return statement.

Comment: because of you use return before TotalCostTextBox1.Text = result.ToString();
when you write return current block close

Comment: This should help solve your problem - https://tutorials.visualstudio.com/vs-get-started/debugging | https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/getting-started-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2017

Comment: Change int to void and remove return after look at your designer.cs is it have code like this `code` this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.ConfirmForm_Load); `code` is not add this code

Comment: @erdiyılmaz Thankyou your comment poped something in my head which was related to your comment I fixed it and now my problem is solved. thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place below assignment statement before return

```
TotalCostTextBox1.Text = result.ToString();
```

Your final code should be like below code:

```
private void ConfirmForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectQuery = "SELECT Sum(RowTotalColumn) FROM InvoiceTable";
    var sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, sqlcon);
    var result = sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar();
    TotalCostTextBox1.Text = result.ToString();
    //return int.Parse(result.ToString());
}
```

Also you need to check the event binding with ConfirmForm_Load function. To verify this please check if following line is available in ConfirmForm.Designer.cs

```
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.ConfirmForm_Load);
```

Answer (score 2):

The return type of your method is int, this is why you are getting error. You can change your method return type to [`void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/void) and remove the return keyword:

```
private void ConfirmForm_Load
```

And

```
var result = sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar();
int x = int.Parse(result.ToString());
TotalCostTextBox1.Text = x.ToString();
```

Comment: Ok I got it its okay I had manipulated something unintentionally in the designer.cs now it works. thank you...

Answer (score 1):

> Unreachable code detected

Well that's cause you are assigning to your Textbox after the `return` statement which will never reach. it's a event handler and thus should of `void` type since event handler doesn't return anything.

```
private void ConfirmForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectQuery = "SELECT Sum(RowTotalColumn) FROM InvoiceTable";
    var sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, sqlcon);
    var result = sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar();                
    this.TotalCostTextBox1.Text = result.ToString();
```

Considering `TotalCostTextBox1` is the instance name of the `TotalCostTextBox1` control

Comment: Ok I got it its okay I had manipulated something unintentionally in the designer.cs now it works.Thank you buddy...